# How to get / generate access token from azure OAuth 2.0 token (v2) endpoints?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I want to get an access token from given URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I am passing the following parameters, as mentioned int he Microsoft docs:
`client_id`, `scope`, `client_secret`, `grant_type`.

When I hit this URL, I get a "400 Bad Request" response.

When I try the same from Postman, it succeeds and provides me an access token:

[image: success postman request]

But not from my code:

```
public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationToken(string clientId, string ServicePrincipalPassword, string AzureTenantId) {
            var result = "";
            var requestURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var model = new {
                client_id = clientId,
                scope = "{clentID}/.default",
                client_secret = ServicePrincipalPassword,
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            };

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(requestURL)) {
                Content = httpContent
            };

            using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)) {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;
                } else {
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Try to read the response stream. You should get more details about the error. Please update your question with that error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your http request format is not correct , try :

```
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
              { "client_id", "ClientID" },
              { "client_secret", "YourSecret" },
              { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
              { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" },
            });

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(requestURL))
{
    Content = content
};

using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just as an addition to [Nan Yu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56180425/325697), you may want to consider using a library for this, instead of trying to implement this yourself.

For example, with the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for .NET, you would obtain an access token like this:

```
// Setup MSAL
var client = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("{client-id}")
    .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0")
    .WithClientSecret(/* retrieve from secure storage, do *NOT* put the secret in your code! */)
    .Build();

// Retrieve an access token
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var authResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

// The access token is in $authResult.AccessToken
```

One important advantage is that you don't need to worry about keeping track of the token validity to know when you need to get a fresh token. If you need to get a new token, you just call `AcquireTokenForClient` again, and it will figure out for you if it needs to get a new token, or if you can use the one which is already cached.

Comment: Any clues on how to specify grant_type = "client_credentials" with this approach? It seems like due to its absence I get a token but it results into 401 when being used. But when grant_type is sent via Postman request, obtained token is OK.

Comment: The whole point of using the library is that you don't need to worry about the protocol details, such as which `grant_type` value to use. The library will choose the correct one based on how you configure the client. In the example in this answer (a confidential client using a client secret), the resulting token request *does* use `grant_type=client_credentials`.

Comment: Yep, after I wrote comment I had a look at method documentation and realized it. Thank you a lot. My problem was that scope was initialized by a different value from what I expected. 
However there's an interesting behavior I found - whenever I use one or the other scope, token is generated. But when both scopes are passed as an array, I get an exception about JWT token could not be generated. I could easily solve it in a different manner, so not an issue for me. 
Anyway, great thanks to you for quick reply and for initial post as it was very helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Go the "Expose an Api" blade of your app.
2. Locate the App ID URI value. Say the App ID Uri is http://abc.pqr
3. Your resource to obtain the token for would be `http://abc.pqr/.default`